# How to redirect index.php to root in htaccess with exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, s3-rewrite-rules

I have a [site](http://www.kianwebdesign.com/en) and I want to do .htaccess rewrite to redirect all site from `/index.php` to `/`, but except `/contact-us` page.

So how can I add an exception to this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/(.*) $1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

So that when I enter:

```
index.php?option=com_baforms&view=form&form_id=1
```

It doesn't redirect to:

```
?option=com_baforms&view=form&form_id=1
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483490/redirect-index-php-to-root-except-query-string/40750966?noredirect=1#comment68727967_40750966), but I wasn't able to do it myself.

Comment: Why does it matter? They both go to the same place. The main benefit of having `index.whatever` files is that they aren't required in URLs.

Comment: no it doesn't submit a contact us form if it doesn't contain index.php @Walf

Comment: Does the contact form submit to `/index.php?...` imstead of `/?...`? If so, change it. You shouldn't be redirecting `POST` requests, either, so add a `RewriteCond` to ensure only `GET` or `HEAD` requests get redirected.